# Why does the android device got stuck or hang If we dynamically set bottom navigation menu selected item inside onCreateView() method?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

setting "bottomNavigationView?.selectedItemId = R.id.menu_home" inside onCreateView() of fragment will stuck app and my android device.

Comment: make a another function for bottomnavigationview outside the oncreateview()

Comment: @PrashantPandey but I want to set it inside onCreatedView()

Answer (score 0):

you cant create a bottom navigation in on create as you are implementing the bottom navigation view so it is mandatory to create it outside it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

onCreateView method is an inflating view and onViewCreated method it's making sure the view is inflated so you can implement selected item id on onViewCreated method.